# Android JSON Volley not parsing Wordpress JSON Api

Tags: android, json, wordpress, android-studio, android-fragments

Hello guys i've used a RecyclerViewer to parse JSON Data with Volley, i got it to work. My only problem right now is parsing json from a wordpress JSON API Url.

If i create a json file on my server and acces that it works fine. Even with the same data as in the url generated by wordpress

My quess is that the Wordpress Json is giving different cache controls or something.

I prefer to keep the data and the url safe. But if someone can help me out to figure out why the code i'm going to provide below, is not working

**Json Headers Wordpress Request**

AnswerHeaders

```
X-Firefox-Spdy  h2
cache-control   no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0
content-encoding    gzip
content-type    application/json; charset=UTF-8
date    Mon, 29 Oct 2018 23:26:10 GMT
expires Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT
server  nginx
x-powered-by    PleskLin
```

RequestHeaders

```
Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language nl,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
Connection  keep-alive
Host    secret
TE  Trailers
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests   1
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:63.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/63.0
```

**Working Json Headers**

Answerheaders

```
Accept-Ranges   bytes
Connection  Upgrade, Keep-Alive
Content-Encoding    gzip
Content-Length  4824
Content-Type    application/json
Date    Mon, 29 Oct 2018 23:23:23 GMT
ETag    "faf7-579664b90ce89-gzip"
Keep-Alive  timeout=2, max=100
Last-Modified   Mon, 29 Oct 2018 23:19:04 GMT
Server  Apache/2
Upgrade h2,h2c
Vary    Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
```

RequestHeaders

```
Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language nl,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
Connection  keep-alive
Host    secret
If-Modified-Since   Mon, 29 Oct 2018 23:19:04 GMT
If-None-Match   "faf7-579664b90ce89-gzip"
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests   1
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:63.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/63.0
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Context mContext;
    private Activity mActivity;

    private TextView mTextView;
    private String mJSONURLString = "secret<3n";
    private RequestQueue requestQueree;
    private ArrayList<TheItem> StringList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mContext = getApplicationContext();
        mActivity = MainActivity.this;

        mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_test);

        mTextView.setText("");

        // Initialize a new RequestQueue instance
        StringList = new ArrayList<>();
        requestQueree = Volley.newRequestQueue(mContext);

        Button btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_1);
        btn1.setOnClickListener(btnListener);
        loadData();
        // Initialize a new JsonObjectRequest instance
    }

    private View.OnClickListener btnListener = new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            //do the same stuff or use switch/case and get each button ID and do different
            loadData();
            //stuff depending on the ID
        }

    };

    public void loadData() {
        StringList.clear();
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, mJSONURLString, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        // Do something with response
                        //mTextView.setText(response.toString());

                        // Process the JSON
                        try {
                            // Get the JSON array
                            JSONArray array = response.getJSONArray("posts");

                            // Loop through the array elements
                            for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                                // Get current json object
                                JSONObject student = array.getJSONObject(i);

                                // Get the current student (json object) data
                                String firstName = student.getString("title");

                                Log.e("Output", firstName);
                                // Display the formatted json data in text view
                                StringList.add(new TheItem(firstName));
                            }
                            TheItem currentitem = StringList.get(0);
                            String TheTitle = currentitem.getTitle();
                            mTextView.setText(TheTitle);
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        // Do something when error occurred
                        String errorMessage = error.getClass().getSimpleName();
                        Log.e("error", errorMessage);
                    }
                });

        // Add JsonObjectRequest to the RequestQueue
        requestQueree.add(jsonObjectRequest);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to first Instantiate the RequestQueue like this:

```
final TextView mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
// ...

// Instantiate the RequestQueue.
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
String url ="http://www.google.com";

// Request a string response from the provided URL.
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        // Display the first 500 characters of the response string.
        mTextView.setText("Response is: "+ response.substring(0,500));
    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        mTextView.setText("That didn't work!");
    }
});
```

Comment: I cant see how this will solve it? Could you explain.

Comment: @DionGrendelman,to make a request you first have to make a queue which is called a request queue

Comment: Saad, look at the top i've declared a RequestQueue already, other wise the code would not work in the first place. My only problem is that the json on the headers shown are not working.

Answer (score 0):

It was W3 Total Cache,

The plugin was caching the json file